# How do I fix my debugger from stopping my app as soon as it is connected in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, run-app

I run my app with the "play icon" [image: Play Icon]

Then I connect my Debugger [image]

Android studio will then give me the message:
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 'socket'

My issue is that now my app is no longer running and even though the debugger is connected, I am unable to debug as the app is not running.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the next line where you wish the debugger to pause, it will make your environment to wait until the debugger attaches:

```
 Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

Place a breakpoint after it at the point where you would like to start to debug. I emphasize, **the breakpoint must be at any point "after" such instruction**.

Logically, is assumed that you are executing a **debug build variant**, otherwise the debugger will never attach.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior, if you hoover over the stop button [image]

it will say "stop 'Android Debugger (8600)' indicating that the debugger is on.
[image]